# file_exists working with string, but not $var

Tags: php, var, file-exists

So I'm trying to make a dynamic link page that takes a load of entries, links to an image if it exists, and links to an upload box if it doesn't. For some reason, though, when I pass a variable to file_exists it returns false, even if passing the same location directly returns true. For example:

```
$tempcomp = "dogs/big dogs/misty.puppy.jpg";

                if (file_exists($tempcomp))
                    {
                        echo "YES1";
                    }
                clearstatcache();
                if (file_exists ("dogs/big dogs/misty.puppy.jpg"))
                    {
                        echo "YES2";
                    }
                clearstatcache();
```

This code returns YES2, even though both statements are identical. What causes this kind of behavior?

Comment: could it be because of space in the file name: ../big dogs/...
can you try it with a file that does not have a space in its name?

Comment: Try this please. var_dump(realpath($tempcomp))

Comment: Hm, hidden characters in one of the strings perhaps?

Comment: @DavidLevel That's got it. I must have some kind of formatting error somewhere, but if (file_exists(realpath($tempcomp))) works wonderfully.

Comment: @Raverrn I'm sorry but I tried to reproduce the bug and I did not success. I asked you to use realpath function just to see if it returns false. I tried your function and it works well on Debian server.

Comment: Update: Scratch that - I had some things commented out. Neither file_exists(), realpath(), or fopen() can 'see' the file if given a dynamic variable, but all three will if given a static string.

Comment: Update 2: It's (probably) not file_exists(). I ran a var_dump() on my string and my variable - they're exactly the same, but the variable is listing an extra character. Trim isn't working, so I've got some research to do.